# Given a Paperclip file, how to clean up the filename to be url friendly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

remove non-utf8 characters, downcase, removes spaces. Is there a builtin way in rails to make filenames friendly and safe before paperclip saves?

Comment: Unless you're going to remove spaces _and_ CamelCase, you might just want to replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: I took inspiration from [this article](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/7/13/paperclip-file-rename) some times ago.

Comment: Possible resources: http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/7/13/paperclip-file-rename and https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-strip-strange-characters by @mspanc.